# Aggregating multiple columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Currently my csv looks like this:

| title | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | A11 | 553 | 0 |
| A | A1 | A12 | 94 | 0 |
| A | A1 | A13 | 30 | 0 |
| A | A1 | {n/a} | 0 | 9586 |
| A | A2 | A21 | 200 | 0 |
| A | A2 | {n/a} | 0 | 3950 |
| A | A3 | A31 | 35 | 0 |
| A | A3 | {n/a} | 0 | 2929 |

But I am wanting it to look like this:

| title | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | A11 | 553 | 9586 |
| A | A1 | A12 | 94 | 9586 |
| A | A1 | A13 | 30 | 9586 |
| A | A2 | A21 | 200 | 3950 |
| A | A3 | A31 | 35 | 2929 |

This is my code:

```
def fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order):
    df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)\
                .agg(cols_to_aggregate)
    df['title'] = 'A'
    df = df[cols_order]
    return df


def create_csv(df, month_date):
    cols_to_aggregate = {'field3': 'sum', 'field4': 'sum'}
    cols_order = ['title', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3']
    funCSV = fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order)
    return funCSV
```

Any help would be appreciated as I can't figure out how to match field4 to all of the relevant field2's.

Comment: Do you need change `df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)` to `df.groupby(['title','field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have just updated it as the title is just a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
def fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order):
    df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)\
                .agg(cols_to_aggregate)
    df['title'] = 'A'
    #aggregate field4 to new column
    df['field4'] = df.groupby('field1')['field4'].transform('sum')
    df = df[cols_order]
    return df


def create_csv(df, month_date):
    cols_to_aggregate = {'field3': 'sum', 'field4': 'sum'}
    #aded value 'field4'
    cols_order = ['title', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3','field4']
    funCSV = fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order)
    return funCSV

print (create_csv(df, '2015-01').loc[lambda x: x['field2'].ne('{n/a}')])
  title field1 field2  field3  field4
0     A     A1    A11     553    9586
1     A     A1    A12      94    9586
2     A     A1    A13      30    9586
4     A     A2    A21     200    3950
6     A     A3    A31      35    2929
```

Or if need first non `0` value per `field1` use:

```
def fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order):
    df = df.groupby(['field1', 'field2'], as_index=False)\
                .agg(cols_to_aggregate)
    df['title'] = 'A'
    df['field4'] = df.groupby('field1')['field4'].transform('first')
    df = df[cols_order]
    return df


def create_csv(df, month_date):
    cols_to_aggregate = {'field3': 'sum', 'field4': 'first'}
    cols_order = ['title', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3','field4']
    funCSV = fun(df, cols_to_aggregate, cols_order)
    return funCSV

print (create_csv(df.replace({'field4':{0:np.nan}}), '2015-01').loc[lambda x: x['field2'].ne('{n/a}')])
  title field1 field2  field3  field4
0     A     A1    A11     553  9586.0
1     A     A1    A12      94  9586.0
2     A     A1    A13      30  9586.0
4     A     A2    A21     200  3950.0
6     A     A3    A31      35  2929.0
```